# Wrong displaying navigation bar on iPhone 6/6+

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I got an issue about setting up navigation bar.

I have a UIViewController which is embedded in Navigation Controller.

In view did load I write:

> ```
> [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_nav_white.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
> ```

But it's displayed wrong on right and left side. It happens on iPhone 6/6+, good for iPhone 4,5. Do you know the reason? Thank you!

[image]

If i make customizing uinavigationcontroller with init method, it displays well. I don't understand why:

> - (id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController background:(UIImage *)background font:(UIFont *)font{

```
if (self = [super initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]) {

    if([self.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)] ) {

        NSShadow *shadow = [NSShadow new];
        [shadow setShadowColor: [UIColor clearColor]];
        [shadow setShadowOffset: CGSizeMake(1, -1.0f)];


        if (SYSTEM_VERSION <7) {

            settings = @{
                         UITextAttributeFont                 :  font,
                         UITextAttributeTextColor            :  [UIColor whiteColor],
                         UITextAttributeTextShadowColor      :  [UIColor clearColor],
                         UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset     :  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(1,-1)],
                         };
        }
        else{

            settings = @{
                         NSFontAttributeName                 :  font,
                         NSForegroundColorAttributeName      :  [UIColor whiteColor],
                         NSShadowAttributeName               :  shadow,
                         };
        }

        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:settings];
        [self.navigationBar setTitleVerticalPositionAdjustment:2.0f forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
        [self.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleDefault];

    }
}
return self;
```

}